# Break from called method in java

Tags: java

I have two methods:

```
public void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        a();
    }
}

public void a() {
    // ...
}
```

Suppose the `test` method is fixed, I can not modify it.

How can I break the for loop in the `a` method?

Comment: You can throw an exception.

Comment: What is the meaning of fixed ?

Comment: Fixed - He probably is implying a method that he cannot edit.

Comment: you says that you cant modify test() then how can you add a() in test ()?

Comment: Sorry, I mean do not modify the test method. @CAMOBAP, thanks, I don't want to exit the application. Probably throw exception is the best choice. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw an unchecked exception.

Another solution is to sub-class the class which has the first method and fix it so it can stop early e.g. if a() return true.

Comment: Thanks, the second solution is what I mean test method is fixed, I do not want to return in test method. But throwing exception really works.

Comment: The original method with a loop won't expect an unchecked exception, but an overridden method can, and continue as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an exception, or you could simply use `break;`. This is a little less work, as you don't need to handle an exception at all.
Example:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        foo();
    }

    public static void foo()
    {
        int i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("in loop: " + i);
            if(i == 5) break;
        }
        System.out.println("end value: " + i);
        System.out.flush();
    }
}
```

The end value of `i` will be 5.